# How to format DelimitedReader in MathNet Numerics to read in empty strings as zero?

Tags: c#, csv, math.net, mathnet-numerics

I'm reading from a CSV file that has a lot of empty cells and I want to read in the empty cells as zero. Is there a way to do this using DelimitedReader?

I'm looking at the documentation for DelimitedReader and I see that it takes four parameters:

•sparse: Whether the the returned matrix should be constructed as sparse (true) or dense (false).
Default: false.
•delimiter: Number delimiter between numbers of the same line. Supports Regex groups.
Default: \s (white space).
•hasHeaders: Whether the first row contains column headers or not. If true, the first line will be skipped.
Default: false.
•formatProvider: The culture to use. It is often a good idea to use InvariantCulture, to make the format independent from the local culture. Default: null

I think I might need to use the formatProvider parameter to do this, but I'm not sure how I would use it.

Answer (score 0):

I would expect it to interpret an empty value as 0 as well, no matter how it is configured. So this qualifies as a bug. Could you open an issue/ticket about this [here](https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/issues)? Thanks!

Comment: Just opened a ticket. Incidentally, I noticed that the zero appears at the end of the row in some cases and doesn't appear at all in other cases. I outlined both cases in the ticket: https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-numerics/issues/241